# Optimum Dimensions of a Closed Cylindrical Can

Tags: calculus

I was doing math for time-killing, and I stumbled upon this question:

"Find the most economical dimensions for a closed cylindrical can containing a quart."

My work:

I do know that the volume $V$of cylinder is $V = \pi r^2h.$ I applied differentiation like this:$$d(V) = d(\pi r^2h) $$ Then: $$dV = \pi r^2 + 2\pi rh.$$ I set the $dV$ to be zero to get the optimum dimensions: $$0 = \pi r^2 + 2\pi rh$$ $$-\pi r^2 = 2\pi rh$$ $$-r=2h$$

The solution I got seems legitimate because I would just ignore the negative sign, getting the dimensions the radius must equal to twice of the cylinder's height.

And that's one fat can we got. In the book I used the answer is the dimensions must be Diameter = Height.

How do you get the optimum dimensions Diameter = Height?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449563/height-radius-ratio-for-maximum-volume-cylinder-of-given-surface-area

Comment: @BenjaminMoss Well....in this case.....I never thought that a restraint which is surface area must be constant if I try on different combinations of radiuses and heights of cylinder can. I often thought that surface area would change if I try to change cylindrical can sizes:-)

Comment: The Lagrange multiplier method is a pretty elegant approach indeed, although the accepted answer in the link I sent uses a technique more similar to your approach.

Comment: @BenjaminMoss Hmmm...I never heard of Lagrange multipliers......but I thank you for your efforts in helping me, and a new topic to be learned:-)