# Cylinder dimensions based on volume and (height:width) ratio

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

One <sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>[image: tin can of Mini Ravioli]</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub> has dimensions
**`4.4" tall × 2.9" wide`**.

Since `1" = 2.54cm` and $V = \pi r^{2}h$, that means:

```
                     Imperial     Metric
        Height         4.4"      11.2 cm
        Width/Depth    2.9"       7.4 cm
        Volume        29.1 in³  476.3 cm³
```

I have consumed $10348$ cans of Mini Ravioli.
**∴** I have consumed `~174 ft³` (`~4.9 m³`) of Mini Ravioli.

---

**If all that Mini Ravioli had come in *One Big Can*** — having the same $W:H$ proportion as the original ($\approx 2:3$) — ***what would the can dimensions be?***

[image]<sub>***Scaling Volume*** like this has always confused me.  Obviously I can't just multiply the width & height by the quantity, or else the new volume would be `> 32 trillion inches³`.  I suspect the solution is related to [**this answer**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449563/height-radius-ratio-for-maximum-volume-cylinder-of-given-surface-area) but I can't quite wrap my head around it.</sub>

---

### Edit: <sub><sup>(Solution)</sup></sub>

It would be, relative to average adult height, ***this** big*:

[image]

```
7.9 feet tall × 5.4 feet wide
2.4 metres tall × 1.6 metres wide
```

Comment: Just for the record, I *do* have more practical applications for this than *just* the ravioli... All I *actually* want for *this* is the scaled Height/Width, but it would nice to finally understand the process *once and for all.*  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proportion between W and H is $2:3$. So $3W=2H$
$$V=\pi r^2 h=\pi\times\left(\frac{W}{2}\right)^2\times H=\frac\pi4\times W^2\times\frac32W=\frac{3\pi}{8}W^3$$
So given the volume, you can work out the width of a can with this proportion.

---

Alternative method: You already know the volume, width and height for a smaller version of this cylinder. Now you want width and height for a cylinder with a different volume, but the same proportions, i.e. a scaled up version of the small cylinder. Say the small cylinder has volume $v$, height $h$, width $w$ and the large one has volume $V$, height $H$, width $W$. We have that $V=\lambda v$ for some number $\lambda$ which you can work out. $V$ is a volume, $W$ is a length, so if $V$ has scaled up by $\lambda$, then $W$ would have scaled up by $\lambda^{1/3}$. This is true because volume is proportional to length cubed. It can also be shown to be true by the method above. So we have that $$W=\lambda^{1/3}w\\H=\lambda^{1/3}h$$

Comment: *Uhhh..* I sometimes refer to myself as a "math person"... but definitely not around here.  I appreciate the answer but understanding it will take me sometime.  For example, I've never seen or heard of a [Lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda#Lower-case_letter_%CE%BB) until about 12 minutes ago.

Comment: As for the first method, uhhh, `300742≈(3π÷8)×(WIDTH³)` ?...so `300742.6 in³=1.178097245*(WIDTH³)` so `255278.2613 =(WIDTH³)` so **`Width=63.4`** (÷2×3) **`Height=95.1`** ?   ...er no, *that ain't right*: that would be a volume of `451113.9 in³`.

Comment: Lambda is just a symbol i used there, you can use any letter you want. It just represents the scale that is used. In response to the second comment, where did you get 300742 from? $V$ is the _volume_. So this would be $4.9\,m^3$ or $174\,ft^3$. (You can choose whichever of these you want to use, based on what units you want to find $W$ in. In metres, this gives $W=1.61\dots\,m$.

Comment: @ashleedawg Ah sorry, I have just noticed you did it in $in^3$. In fact your computed $H$ and $W$ are correct. They give a volume of $$V=\pi\times\left(\frac{63.4}2\right)^2\times 95.1=300226\approx 300742\,\,\,\checkmark$$ I don't know how you got $451113\,in^3$? Note, we don't get the exact same volume only due to rounding errors, but we do get it correct to $3$ significant figures.

Comment: thanks, that was helpful. (I added an updated version of the "actual size".) - but honest, this knowledge will be re-purposed beyond ravioli.